# Python ZIP file creation without the hierarchy

Tags: python

I am creating a ZIP file in python, containing some files, and unfortunately the output contains a hierarchy inside the ZIP file and I just want the files without any folders to be contained in the ZIP file. This is my code:

```
    name = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    name = '../models/' + str(name) + '.zip'
    with ZipFile(os.path.abspath(name), 'w') as zip:
        for file in filies:
            zip.write(file)
    zip.close()
```

I want the structure to be:
name.zip/file.png

and it currently is:
name.zip/users/me/desktop/project/file.png

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of `write` allows you to specify the name of the file within the archive https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write

So you could so something like...

```
from os.path import basename

name = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
name = '../models/' + str(name) + '.zip'
with ZipFile(os.path.abspath(name), 'w') as zip:
    for file in filies:
        zip.write(file, arcname=basename(file))
zip.close()
```

Comment: No worries Vedsil!

Answer (score 1):

From [`zipfile` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write)

> `ZipFile.write(filename, arcname=None, compress_type=None, compresslevel=None)`
>
> Write the file named filename to the archive,
> giving it the archive name arcname (by default, this will be the same
> as filename, but without a drive letter and with leading path
> separators removed).(...)

So you need to provide 2nd argument when using `.write`, you might use `os.path.basename` to extract filename from path, that is to do

```
name = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
name = '../models/' + str(name) + '.zip'
with ZipFile(os.path.abspath(name), 'w') as zipf:
    for file in filies:
        zipf.write(file, os.path.basename(file))
```

Observe that I changed `zip` to `zipf` to avoid overshadowing built-in function `zip` and removed line with `.close`, as you do not need to close when you use `ZipFile` instance as context manager (`with` statement).

Comment: Renaming `zip` to `zipf` is a good call.